# RSA - export public key for different language

Tags: c#, cryptography, rsa

I'm using C# to generate an RSA public/private key to encrypt user information.  I need to make the public key and exponent available thought for other systems and languages.  They will be signing the data and the C# web service will decrypt it and act upon it.

Right now, I have

`RSA rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048); // Generate a new 2048 bit RSA key
    RSAParameters par = rsa.ExportParameters(false);`

But the results for par.Exponent and par.Modulo are byte arrays.  How can I convert the exponent to a string that can be parsed in another language.  The samples in other languages I've seen seem to b

Comment: *signing* is done with the private key, *verifying* is done with the public key. *encrypting* is done with the public key, *decrypting* is done with the private key.

Comment: @gregs - I apologize for that, I removed the comment and appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a plain hex string or Base64 encoding - both are well-established methods of transporting binary data as a string:

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 253, 254, 255 };

// hexString will be "010203FDFEFF"
string hexString = string.Concat(byteArray.Select(b => b.ToString("X2")));

// b64String will be "AQID/f7/"
string b64String = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);
```

(Note that if you're not using .NET4 then you'll need to pass an array to the `Concat` method rather than an `IEnumerable<T>`. You can do this easily enough by bolting a `ToArray` call onto the `Select`.)

Comment: Hex implementation was the easiest to get other languages to use it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

rsa.ToXmlString will export your key as an xml file.

Otherwise, take the byte array and use Convert.ToBase64String method

This will give you a base64 representation of you key parameters which should be able to be used by any language.

You may also find the OpenSSLKey library useful for using RSA keys between languages. 
http://www.jensign.com/opensslkey/

Answer (score 0):

Convert to hex:

```
Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(theByteArray, 2), 16);
```